# Update row by substracting values using parameters on SQL Server CE

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I am trying to come up with a query using SQL Server CE. I have a column `Qty` and I want to subtract from the column as the user enters an amount. Here is what I have:

```
UPDATE ItemInventoryControl
SET Stocks = SUM(Stocks - @Stocks)
WHERE (ItemName = @ItemName)
```

But is not working, I get an error:

> SQL Execution Error
>
> Error Source: SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider
>   Error Message: Not Implemented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my mistake, it should be:

```
UPDATE       ItemInventoryControl
SET          Stocks = Stocks - @Stocks
WHERE        (ItemName = @ItemName)
```